# When I put props in state, state is not updated even if props is updated

Tags: reactjs

When a parent component passes a props named title to a child component and puts the props into the child component's state, when the parent component's title is moved to the child component instead, the props is updated, but the state is not updated and the past title is retained.

Props are updated, but the State using Props is not updated.

How do I update the state of a child component when the parent component is updated?

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            title:''
        };
    }

<Child title={this.state.title}/>)}
```

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            title: props.title
        };
    }
```

Comment: The constructor is.. well.. constructing, it sets the initial values, it doesn't permanently tie the props and state together.

Comment: Where are you updating anything?  Where are you trying to observe that update?  Please provide a complete and runnable example demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying props to state seems redundant and anti-pattern, but if you need to do it (for reasons like **editing** details in a form), you can copy the props into state using `constructor` and **update** (conditionally) it when the props' value is changed using `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method:

```
class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: this.props.title // Copy
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.title !== prevProps.title) {
      this.setState({
        title: this.props.title // Update conditionally when it is changed in props
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <>{this.state.title}</>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Originally I would like to do that, but I set it to state because I want to be able to edit it as the value of the form. Is there any workaround in such a case?

Comment: I want to be able to send the changed title value from the child component to the server side without the need for the parent component value to be updated.
If the value is changed in the parent component, I want to force the child component to change its value.

Answer (score 2):

Don't store the same state in multiple locations; synchronizing them will be a pain. Instead, pass down the title and a state setter function to the child, eg:

```
<Child
  title={this.state.title}
  setTitle={title => { this.setState({ title }); }}
/>
```

And don't keep state in the child - only use the `title` prop. Call the `setTitle` prop when you need to update from the child.